# Android - referencing string array using another string with getIdentifier() and getStringArray

Tags: android, arrays, string

I have a variety of string arrays I want to access depending on which one the user decides to use.  I don't want to use a SQLite DB because I am very new to Android/Java and I have struggled to find examples so I'm guessing this is a rather poor way to do it but all the same...

If I have in a xml file this:

```
    <string-array name="bob">
<item>1</item>
<item>4</item>
<item>7</item>
<item>11</item>
</string-array>
```

And in a Java file this:

```
String name = "bob";
```

Why does the following not work?  It crashes on startup every time.

```
int holderint = getResources().getIdentifier("name", "array",
                this.getPackageName());
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(holderint);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Shouldn't this line be like this?

```
int holderint = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "array",
                this.getPackageName()); // You had used "name"
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(holderint);
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, Rahul.  Thank you so much!  The website I was using was apparently wrong (or poorly implemented by me).  Thanks again!