# Passing information to new activity

Tags: android, eclipse, string, android-intent

I've got multiple buttons, when each one is clicked they all launch the same activity. Depending on the button clicked the second activity will load a different String Array, how do I pass and catch a string array via an intent? Note the String Arrays are saved in an .xml file.

At the moment the second activity is just loading a specific array

```
    res = getResources();
    arraytoload = res.getStringArray(R.array.ninetyseven);
```

How would I get the button to send a message containing for example (R.array.twentyfive) and then have that load as arraytoload.

First activity

```
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.test.MainActivity");
            intent.putExtra("id", "ninetyseven");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Second activity

```
private String[] arraytoload;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String idString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(idString, "array", getPackageName());
    arraytoload = res.getStringArray(id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity, in the `onClick()` method for your button.

```
String s = "hello!";
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewClass.class);
intent.putExtra("extraInfo1",s);
startActivity(intent);
```

In NewClass.class, in the `onCreate()` method.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String passedString = intent.getStringExtra("extraInfo1","doesn't exist!");
System.out.println(passedString);
```

This will print "hello!"

The second argument in `getStringExtra()` is the default value, if not string is found along with the intent with the given tag (in this case, "extraInfo1" is the tag). `passedString` will be set to "doesn't exist!" if you start the intent somewhere else and don't attach the string with the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the button clicked, send the array `name` with the intent like:

Button 1:

```
i.putExtra("id", "ninetyseven");
```

Button 2:

```
i.putExtra("id", "ninetyeight");
```

then retrieve it in the Second Activity:

```
String idString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
```

then in order to get the array you can use the following code:

```
String idString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(idString, "array", getPackageName());
arraytoload = res.getStringArray(id);
```

this line of code:

```
getIdentifier(idString, "array", getPackageName());
```

is to generate this: `R.array.ninetyseven`

hope this help you solve your issue.

Comment: This is helping a bit however I'm getting a null pointer at arraytoload = res.getStringArray(id);, not sure why though.

Comment: oh sorry.. please change "id" to "array" check the edit part within `getIdentifier(idString, "id", getPackageName());` to `getIdentifier(idString, "array", getPackageName());`

Comment: here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565108/android-referencing-string-array-using-another-string-with-getidentifier-and) that worked with somebody.. can you `Log.d("id", ""+ id);` before you assign `arraytoload` so we check the generated id

Answer (score 0):

you can simply  parse the array resource id as an extra in intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class)
intent.putExtra("arrayResourceId", R.array.ninetyseven);
startActivity(intent);
```

in your second activity, onCreate method

```
int arrayResourceId = getIntent().getIntExtra("arrayResourceId", -1);
arraytoload = res.getStringArray(arrayResourceId);
```