# Accessing intArray by its name without knowing it

Tags: android, xml

I have an xml file, that is in `./values` and looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <integer-array name="Bulbasaur">
        <item name="hp">0</item>
        <item name="atk">0</item>
        <item name="def">0</item>
        <item name="speatk">1</item>
        <item name="spedef">0</item>
        <item name="speed">0</item>
    </integer-array>

    <integer-array name="Ivysaur">
        <item name="hp">0</item>
        <item name="atk">0</item>
        <item name="def">0</item>
        <item name="speatk">1</item>
        <item name="spedef">2</item>
        <item name="speed">0</item>
    </integer-array>
...
</resources>
```

I'd like to access the intArrays by their name, but I can't use the `R.id.stuff`, because I get the name from an input. I already tried to use `getIdentifier()` then `getIntArray()`, like this:

```
getResources().getIntArray(getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfArray", "int[]", MyActivity.this.getPackageName())
```

But it didn't work. What am I doing wrong? How do I access those arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7565138/5101816). You rather want to use `"array"` instead of `"int[]"` as a second parameter of `Resources#getIdentifier` method.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much :)